# I can't see "Install Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud" options in 11.10?

Tags: installation, cloud

I downloaded "ubuntu-11.10-server-amd64.iso" and tried to boot in VMware and install "Install Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud" but i can't see this option in first install menu?

please tell me what is problem?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud was replaced with Ubuntu Cloud Infrastructure in 11.10. You can find information about that here:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure11.10

and here for later versions:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure